# Django class based views and formsets

Tags: django

I have a class-based view called `OrganizationsCreateView` that includes a formset attached to a model form as an instance variable of that form.  This works fine when the user enters data -- a new object is created fine.  When the user wants to add additional rows to the formset, I have a submit button that triggers a conditional in the CreateView's post method:

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    if 'add_email' in request.POST:

        cp = request.POST.copy()
        cp['emails-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(request.POST['emails-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1
        self.initial_emails = cp

    return super(OrganizationsCreateView,self).post(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

This adds rows just fine, but unfortunately it also adds a new object each time the user adds a new row.  How/where should I short-circuit this object adding behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying the response flow of Django's class-based views, here is the post method I am using which works great:

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    if 'add_email' in request.POST:
        # Set the object like BaseCreateView would normally do
        self.object = None

        # Copy the form data so that we retain it after adding a new row
        cp = request.POST.copy()
        cp['emails-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(request.POST['emails-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1
        self.initial_emails = cp

        # Perform steps similar to ProcessFormView
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        # Render a response identical to what would be rendered if the form was invalid
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    return super(OrganizationsCreateView,self).post(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

The other important part is the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(OrganizationsCreateView,self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['initial_emails'] = self.initial_emails
    return kwargs
```