# Django - Add row to formset in class based view WITHOUT javascript

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am attempting to create a class based form view with an inline formset. I would like an 'add' button that will add a new row to the formset, and I would like it to work without javascript.

I have found some helpful websites, which have allowed me to create some rough code (below).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11910420/3800244: Provides an elegant / DRY method for adding formsets to a CBV.
http://pytipz.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/django-adding-inline-formset-rows.html: Shows how to add rows to a formset in a view, but it appears to be for a function based view.

My use case is a website for card game. I have a table of cards, a table of decks, and a table of cards-in-decks. The cards table is filled with data, and as people create decks, they need to be able to select cards for that deck (all on the same page/form). Here is some rough code of what I have so far;

**models.py**

```
class Card(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Deck(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField() 

class CardsInDeck(models.Model):
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DeckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deck

CardsInDeckFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Deck, CardsInDeck, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class Deck_FormView(generic.edit.FormView):
    template_name = 'create_deck.html'
    model = Deck
    form_class = DeckForm

    success_url = 'viewdeck' #just an example

    def get_formsets(self):
        return {
            'cards': CardsInDeckFormSet(self.request.POST or None, prefix='cards'),
        }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Deck_FormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formsets'] = self.get_formsets()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        if 'add_card' in request.POST:
            request.POST = request.POST.copy()
            request.POST['cards-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(request.POST['cards-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))


        formsets = self.get_formsets()
        if (form.is_valid() and all((f.is_valid() for f in formsets.values()))):
            return self.form_valid(form, formsets)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form, formsets):
        self.object = form.save()

        for name, formset in formsets.items():
            formset_save_func = getattr(self, 'formset_{0}_valid'.format(name), None)
            if formset_save_func is not None:
                formset_save_func(formset)
            else:
                formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def formset_cards_valid(self, formset):
        cards_formsets = formset.save(commit=False)
        for i in cards_formsets:
            i.deck = self.object
            i.save()
```

**create_deck.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cards in deck</legend>
        {{ formsets.cards.management_form }}

        {% for form in formsets.cards %}
            {{ form.id }}
            <div class="inline {{ formsets.cards.prefix }}">
                {{ form }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <input type='submit' name='add_card' value="Add another card" />
    </fieldset>

    <br>

    <input type='hidden' name='action' value="deck">
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value="Save Deck" />

</form>
```

So my code uses the methods from my initial references. It displays the form and formset, and clicking the "Add" button reloads the page with an extra formset row. Saving also works.
**The problems are**; the new row is created without any 'defaults' (ie nothing selected in the card select-input, and the default quantity of 1 is not entered in the number-input). Also, the new 'empty' row is passed through validation, and the HTML renders with "This field is required." errors for each field.

I would like to resolve these problems, to make it more functional for the user. I am not sure how to do this though. I wonder if it may have something to do with setting is_bound to the form/formset? I also believe the following link may be related, but I could not work out how to implement it (if it is indeed the solution): [Django class based views and formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890919/django-class-based-views-and-formsets)

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution by 'manually' setting the properties for each field of the new formset form. Here is the amended `def post` that does so.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    formsets = self.get_formsets()

    if 'add_card' in request.POST:
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        request.POST['cards-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(request.POST['cards-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1

        # This is the new block of code that loops over each base field,
        # and uses the initial values provided.
        new_formset_id = request.POST['cards-TOTAL_FORMS'] - 1
        for field in formsets['cards'].empty_form.base_fields:
            request.POST['cards-{0}-{1}'.format(new_formset_id, field)] = formsets['cards'].empty_form.base_fields[field].initial

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    if (form.is_valid() and all((f.is_valid() for f in formsets.values()))):
        return self.form_valid(form, formsets)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

This gives no validation errors when adding a form. Upon saving the main form, these empty/default formset forms are ignored.